# Can aws cdk provide remote state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws, aws-cdk

Terraform has a remote stack via well documented plugins, i.e. terraform.backend.s3
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html

Can aws cdk provide remote state for the stacks?
I can't find in documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/awscdk.pdfstack

I ask about aws cdk because I  found pure documentation about aws cdktf.
Found that cloud cloudfront generates a lot of json file as well as uses it. Does the contain state?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CDK uses CloudFormation under the hood, which manages the remote state of the infrastructure in a similar way like a Terraform state-file.
You get the benefit of AWS taking care of state management for you (for free) without the risks of doing it yourself and messing up your state file.

The drawback is that if there is drift between the state CloudFormation thinks resources are in and their actual state, things get tricky.

Comment: I found that aws cdk creates many json files locally. Could they contain state?

Comment: Some of them are recommended to check into the repo, but not because the contain state about the infrastructure. The CDK uses some of them internally. I recommend you use the provided `.gitignore` to decide which stuff to version control. **All state information about the infrastructure is maintained within CloudFormation though**.